# how to route "/" (default url) in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to route "/" to some virtual url say www.abc.com/india, but u i am not able to route it.

How can I route the default Url in MVC.

I have written this is route.config

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "HomePage",
           url: "/",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "index" }
           );
```

and my test function is

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Home_Index_test_with_no_Parameter()
    {
        var context = new StubHttpContextForRouting(requestUrl: "~/");
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);

        // Act
        var routeData = routes.GetRouteData(context);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(routeData, "~/ url is getting routed properly");
        Assert.AreEqual("home", routeData.Values["controller"],
                        "~/ url is not getting routed properly");
        Assert.AreEqual("index", routeData.Values["action"], "~/ url is not getting routed properly");

    }
```

but this test fails

Comment: Where it fails? Any chance to debug? Or maybe check for controller name as one you specify (instead of differently cased `home`)?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had given the answer you can check if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey thank every one for help

The problem is that we cant use "/" as prefix in url to route. below is the working code

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "HomePage",
           url: "",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "index" }
           );
```

Unit Test for it

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Home_Index_test_with_no_Parameter()
    {
        var context = new StubHttpContextForRouting(requestUrl: "~/");
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);

        // Act
        var routeData = routes.GetRouteData(context);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(routeData, "~/ url is getting routed properly");
        Assert.AreEqual("Home", routeData.Values["controller"],
                        "~/ url is not getting routed properly");
        Assert.AreEqual("index", routeData.Values["action"], "~/ url is not getting routed properly");

    }
```